# Mixed data type tensor-flow based random forest regression

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

As the topic suggests I would like to create tensor-flow based random forest regression, using python for our data set which contains the following columns:

HotelName(text& categorical),Country(text categorical). Review(text..?), date( continous or categorical not sure...) and some continous valued columns.
My questions are:

1. What should be the exact categories of the data types we mentioned above, and is any mapping/discretization of the features necessary( for example, if there are 10 countries, we map them to integers 1-10)
2. How do we implement the random forest tensorflow model? I searched on the internet but only found the iris data set random forest example ( which has only continous data). In the estimator api, one can specify the type of value of each column, but that doesnt work with tensor_forest right? How should I do the implementation?

Thanks and wishing everyone a happy new year!